# How to load returned html after $http.post

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

Sorry if this has been asked already, but I can't find an answer!

I'm posting what could almost be form data using angular, and expecting the backend to return an html page.  How do I *load* that page?

```
$http.post(GENERATE_PRACTICE_EXAM_URL, data).then(
  function(data){
    # data contains the html of a page I'd like to load/redirect to
    # $window.loadAsHtml(data); <-- want to do that
  }
);
```

**CLARIFICATION:**
I know that I can return a url from the server and pull a `$location.path(data.data)`.  But what I want is to return the html of the next page, and load it immediately, to avoid making another request with `$location`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use your server just as data storage. It should return JSON and you should use angular directives to show that data.
But if you really need to get html from server and show it you should create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for that.

There is "link" function where you can get access to html element and then just insert your html like

```
directive('myDirective', function($http){
  return {
    link:function(scope, elem){
          $http.get('your url').then(function(htmlResponse){elem.html(htmlResponse)});
         }
 };
});
```

Comment: Yeah that definitely holds for single page websites, but we're actually using django for our backend and do most of the routing with it, so most of the time the server returns fully formed html and not just data in json.